# overdetermined system of non-linear equations

Tags: proof-explanation, systems-of-equations, intuition

I have to solve an overdetermined system of non-linear equations. My system has a lot of equations, but here, for example, my system has $4$ equations. Because all the variables have to be binary, I have to add equations like 
$x_i^2-x_i$. Now I have $8$ equations with $4$ variables. This system is

$$\begin{aligned}
(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)(1-t) &= 0 \\ 
(1-x)(1-y) &=0  \\ 
(1-y)(1-z)(1-t) &=0 \\ 
(1-x)(1-z)(1-t) &=0 
\end{aligned} \\
x^2 - x = 0,~ y^2-y=0,~z^2-z=0,~t^2-t=0.$$

I know in advance, this system will have solution but I don't know **how to explain it mathematically.** (I know how to solve this system)

How can it be explained, because it is over-determined? What is the criterion? Any reference?

Comment: here are the solutions given by WA:$$\{\{t\to 1,x\to 1,y\to 0,z\to 0\},\{t\to 1,x\to 0,y\to 1,z\to 0\},\{t\to 0,x\to 1,y\to
   1,z\to 0\},\{t\to 1,x\to 1,y\to 1,z\to 0\},\{t\to 0,x\to 1,y\to 0,z\to 1\},\{t\to 1,x\to
   1,y\to 0,z\to 1\},\{t\to 0,x\to 0,y\to 1,z\to 1\},\{t\to 1,x\to 0,y\to 1,z\to 1\},\{t\to
   0,x\to 1,y\to 1,z\to 1\},\{t\to 1,x\to 1,y\to 1,z\to 1\}\}$$

Comment: are all variables independent of one another? Why not simplify this by $X=1-x$, $Y=1-y$, etc. Also, if you have a solution state it.

Comment: Yes, I got that solution, but how to explain mathematically this kind of overdeterminated system will have solutions.

Comment: Yes, all variables are independent of one another

Comment: Yes, I got the solution, it is not the problem. I need mathematical explanation how it is possible.

Comment: The solution can be found by "inspection". For each equation, write the values that makes the left hand side zero, after that find the intersection of all these values.

Comment: If you understand how to discuss this sort of thing when the equations are linear, I think the corresponding generalization for [systems of polynomial equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_polynomial_equations) involves topics like [Gröbner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Solutions_of_a_system_of_algebraic_equations). Unfortunately, I don't really know anything about them.